# MYSQL and PHP field/ column name as variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want to pass a field name in as a parameter. I am very new to PHP and MYSQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated! The function takes in the position and the desired stat. it returns the standard deviation of that particular stat. I am looking to do something like this:

```
function standevplayer($POS, $STAT)
{
    $stat = array();
    if(strcmp($POS, 'QB') === 0)
    {
            $sql = "SELECT "%" .$STAT. "%" FROM Quarterback";
    }

    if(strcmp($POS, 'RB') === 0)
    {
            $sql = "SELECT '%" .$STAT. "%' FROM Runningback";
    }

    if(strcmp($POS, 'WR') === 0)
    {
            $sql = "SELECT '%" .$STAT. "%' FROM Receiving";
    }

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
            array_push($stat, $row['$STAT']);
    }
    $SD = standard_deviation($stat);
    return $SD;
}
```

Comment: BTW mysql_query was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0 use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why the percentage? if `$STAT` is your column name then just do

```
$sql = "SELECT ".$STAT." FROM Quarterback";
```

and for getting the result just use

```
$row[$STAT]
```

Comment: $STAT is a variable.